# What is the purpose of RegisterFmxClasses?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

What is the purpose of RegisterFmxClasses ? When i create some components, i always do RegisterComponents, but in the Delphi source file i see that they also do (not always) RegisterFmxClasses. But i can't understand what is the exact purpose of RegisterFmxClasses. In the help they say :

> Registers a set of FireMonkey classes and adds a set of classes to the
>   FireMonkey group objects.

I create components for the firemonkey framework, but with or without RegisterFmxClasses they work well.

Answer (score 0):

From the [`RegisterFmxClasses()` documentation](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Types.RegisterFmxClasses):

> Call `RegisterFmxClasses` to register a set of custom classes in a single line. Each class is registered by calling `RegisterClass`. Unregistered classes cannot be loaded or saved by the component streaming system.
>
> The `GroupClasses` classes are added to the group where `TFmxObject` resides by calling `GroupDescendentsWith`.

Comment: Thanks raphel, however i still don't understand, because even if i don't call RegisterFmxClasses, my class can be loaded or saved by the component streaming system (ie: the saved and loaded from .fmx file). Or i don't understand what is the component streaming system ?

Comment: So you make no calls to register the component? Could you give a very simple MCVE of a trivial component that can be streamed without any registration code?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, about "no calls to register the component" => no off course I call RegisterComponents, but i don't call RegisterFmxClasses and it's work as expected.

Comment: It's a shame that information is missing from the question. `RegisterComponents` might be fine, depending on what your component actually is. Who knows. We certainly don't.

Comment: This answer is literally just quoting verbatim from the `RegisterFmxClasses()` documentation, without actually providing any insight into explaining what the documentation is trying to say.